# How to get few lines from a .gz compressed file without uncompressing

Tags: gzip, gunzip, zcat

How to get the first few lines from a gziped file ?
I tried zcat, but its throwing an error

```
zcat CONN.20111109.0057.gz|head
CONN.20111109.0057.gz.Z: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

`zcat(1)` can be supplied by either `compress(1)` or by `gzip(1)`. On your system, it appears to be `compress(1)` -- it is looking for a file with a `.Z` extension.

Switch to `gzip -cd` in place of `zcat` and your command should work fine:

```
 gzip -cd CONN.20111109.0057.gz | head
```

Explanation

```
   -c --stdout --to-stdout
          Write output on standard output; keep original files unchanged.  If there are several input files, the output consists of a sequence of independently compressed members. To obtain better compression, concatenate all input files before compressing
          them.

   -d --decompress --uncompress
          Decompress.
```

Comment: BTW, if you are sitting with a *.tar.gz, this will help you out:  `tar -xzOf some_huge_file.tar.gz | head`

Comment: Old thread but this produces a broken pipe with exit status 1 with big  gz files. Any clean workaround?

Comment: Best and easiest workaround I've found so far: use `zless file.gz | head`. `zmore` still leaves you with broken pipe. `zless` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: zless doesn't exit... at least not on my large file. I'm still looking for a way do do this without broken pipe errors...

Answer (score 18):

On a mac you need to use the `<` with zcat:

`zcat < CONN.20111109.0057.gz|head`

Answer (score 17):

On some systems (e.g., Mac), you need to use `gzcat`.

Comment: More specifically `gzcat {file} | head`

Answer (score 4):

If **a continuous range of lines** needs be, one option might be:

`gunzip -c  file.gz | sed -n '5,10p;11q' > subFile`

where the lines between 5th and 10th lines (both inclusive) of `file.gz` are extracted into a new `subFile`. For `sed` options, refer to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands).

If **every, say, 5th line** is required:

`gunzip -c  file.gz | sed -n '1~5p;6q' > subFile`

which extracts the 1st line and jumps over 4 lines and picks the 5th line and so on.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `zcat`, this will show the first 10 rows

```
zcat your_filename.gz | head
```

Let's say you want the 16 first row

```
zcat your_filename.gz | head -n 16
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk snippet will let you show  not only the first few lines - but a range you can specify. It will also add line numbers which i needed for debugging an error message pointing to a certain line way down in a gzipped file.

```
gunzip -c file.gz | awk -v from=10 -v to=20 'NR>=from { print NR,$0; if (NR>=to) exit 1}'
```

Here is the awk snippet used in the one liner above. In awk NR is a built-in variable (Number of records found so far) which usually is equivalent to a line number. the from and to variable are picked up from the command line via the -v options.

```
NR>=from {
   print NR,$0; 
   if (NR>=to) 
     exit 1
}
```